# How to make a phonegap application point to a certain URL?

Tags: ios, cordova

I found other questions about this and I tried the suggested answers which were as follows.

Adjust the config.xml file:

I changed this `<content src="index.html" />` to `<content src="localhost:3000" />`

and also

`<access origin="*" />` to `</content src="localhost:3000" subdomains="true">`

But everytime I launch my application, it is still referring to the index.html file.
I am only trying it on iOS platform.
For testing purposes, I am trying the webpage online everytime, I launch the application using `phonegap serve` form the CLI, the webpage (localhost:3000), still refers to index.html

Any insights on that?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot point a device to `localhost` as `localhost` is an alias of `127.0.0.1` which is not reachable over a network.

You need to point to the actual IP address of the machine that is hosting your code.

Example:

```
<content src="192.75.64.231:3000" subdomains="true" />
```

Comment: I tried doing this and for some reason it's still pointing to index.html, is there any other file I need to change?

Comment: @Ralphyabro which config.xml file are you updating? which folder does the config.xml reside? which version of phonegap/cordova are you implementing?

Comment: @frank the config.xml found in the root of the project where I created my application. It doesn't reside in any specific folder of the created folders, its the myproject folder where I built the app. Version of phonegap is: 4.1.2-0.22.10

Comment: In android I can see **two** `config.xml` files. One in folder `\<project_name>\`` and the second in folder `\<project_name>\platforms\android\res\``. Have you tried changing  the config.xml in `res` folder.

Comment: you need to run `cordova prepare` or `cordova build` after modifying `config.xml`